# Как мне работать с БД через C# для удаления даты которая старше одним днём настоящей/нынешней

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, chat

прошу пожалуйста помощи в организации кода в C# классе Program.cs для удаления даты старше одним днём от нынешней.
Вот смог только разобраться по команде удаления конкретной даты из столбца, но не знаю как описать условие в коде по своей цели.
Сам запрос:
`DELETE FROM dbo.Messages WHERE [When] = '2020-12-13 14:31:46.5894343'`

Часть из самого Program.cs класса:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

            // строка подключения к БД
            string connStr = "Data Source=NAME-SERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ChatDB;Integrated Security=True";
            // создаём объект для подключения к БД
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            // устанавливаем соединение с БД
            conn.Open();
            // запрос
            string sql = "DELETE FROM dbo.Messages WHERE [When] = '2020-12-13 14:31:46.5894343'";
            // объект для выполнения SQL-запроса
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            // закрываем соединение с БД
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Вы кстати в коде не выполняете команду, то есть, все настроили, но ничего не сделали с базой. А так, вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1947469/12888024).

Comment: Пробовал запускать проект и указанная дата из поля удалялась, т.е., код срабатывал вот этот вот:  string sql = "DELETE FROM dbo.Messages WHERE [When] = '2020-12-13 14:31:46.5894343'"; 
У меня из БД строка удалялась и в представлении её не было, или Вы не об этом ?
Просто мне нужно после равенства которое после [When] алгоритм проверки даты и удаления даты которая старше одним днём настоящей/нынешней

Comment: Ну так и указывайте эту дату, а не абстрактный литерал. `WHERE [Дата] > DATEADD(DAY, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: "DELETE FROM dbo.Messages WHERE [17.12.2020] > DATEADD(DAY, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)" 
Так ? Если да, то не работает, из C# класса ничего не происходит, письма за старую дату остались. А почему не абстрактный литерал ? Ведь по идее задумка в том что бы был перебор дат и удаление дат старше одного дня

Comment: А вы делаете [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8)? Я вам об этом выше писал.

Comment: DELETE FROM dbo.Messages WHERE DAY([When]) < DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND MONTH([When]) <= MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
Вот строка запроса которая успешно выполняется в БД SQLExpress, но при использовании этой строки в классе в среде разработки C#, ничего не происходит при исполнении, и когда точку останову делаю, выполнение проходит нормально, ошибок не возникает, компилятор отрабатывает нормально. Почему не могу понять. Спасибо Вам заранее за терпение и помощь.)

Comment: @aepot
Нет я так не делал, в свете моих новых успехов, мне это всё равно рекомендуется сделать ?

Comment: @КириллАртамонов почитайте документацию по ссылке.

Comment: @aepot 
Извините, но там ничего полезного по моей теме не могу найти, в силу вероятно своего малого опыта.
У меня в данный момент проблема не с запросом уже, а с выполнением со стороны кода C#.
В SQL Management всё отрабатывает корректно
Вот код из C#:
string sql = "DELETE FROM dbo.Messages WHERE DAY([When]) < DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND MONTH([When]) <= MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

Comment: Вы прикалываетесь надо мной? Добавьте `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` строчкой выше, чем `command.Close();`. И посмотрите что будет.

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое, Вы мне очень помогли)
Извините что Вас расстроил.

Comment: @КириллАртамонов вы меня не расстроили. Это выглядело скорее весело. Просто будьте внимательны к тому, что вам пишут. Решение вашей проблемы было в первом комментарии под этим вопросом.

Comment: @aepot буду стараться! Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо пользователю @aepot !
Вот верный рабочий код:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

            // строка подключения к БД
            string connStr = "Data Source=NAME-SERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ChatDB;Integrated Security=True";
            // создаём объект для подключения к БД
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            // устанавливаем соединение с БД
            conn.Open();
            // запрос
            string sql = "DELETE FROM dbo.Messages WHERE DAY([When]) < DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) OR MONTH([When]) < MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) OR YEAR([When]) < YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
            // объект для выполнения SQL-запроса
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            //выполняем и закрываем соединение с БД
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не писать запросы, которые выбирают (удаляют) данные по результатам вычисления надо полем. Для того, чтобы узнать результат проверки вида `DAY([When]) < DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) OR MONTH([When])` SQL Server должен будет вычитать значение `[When]` для всех строк, посчитать `DAY([When])`, сделать проверку и тогда уже удалить.

К тому же это значит, что он вычитает с диска всю таблицу. На больших объемах это может быть достаточно дорого и по IO, и по CPU.

Лучше просчитать константу (дату, до которой надо удалить записи), и удалять с прямым сравнением. Это уберет CPU. Можно еще индекс создать (это уберет вычитываение всей таблицы, но может быть дороже, если удаляется большая часть строк таблицы.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Messages 
WHERE [When] < DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Индекс под удаление:

```
CREATE INDEX Messages_When
ON Messages ([when]);
```

Индекс будет эффективен только при удалении небольшого количества строк. Если у вас удаляется почти вся таблица - будет обратный эффект - индекс будет тормозить процесс.

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду, спасибо.

Comment: Но в целом у меня задача была написать чат с сохранением сообщений на один день, т.е., настоящий день.
Вот если будут около полу-миллиона сессий и x2 сообщений от кол-во сессий, то тут уже надо принимать Ваш метод. И его возьму на перспективу, спасибо Вам за это. 
А так у меня это тестовое задание.